# Filter B&W on just a part of a picture with color gradient

Tags: css, filter, colors

I would like my whole web page to be black and white (with a b&w fitler effect), and only a small part of the bottom page to show color. Is this possible with the filters?

examples:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5W1Cf.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jW2Tz.png

Thanks to A Haworth, it's exactly that but to an entiere page and not only a background img :

```html
  
<style>
  
div { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; }
      
.graythencolor {
background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQeNg.jpg"), linear-gradient(00deg, white 7%, black 15%), 
url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQeNg.jpg");background-blend-mode: luminosity, multiply; }
  
</style>
    

<body>
  
<div class="graythencolor"> </div>
  
</body>
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you so much A-Haworth, this is exactly what I want to do ! But I would like to apply this effect to all my page (it's a gallery of pictures). Do you think it is possible to change this to apply it to an entiere page?

Answer (score 0):

We can use the CSS settings of `background-blend-mode` on the background-image, merging it in various ways with a linear gradient.

Here is an example. Obviously you can play around with the % values to get the amount of color you want at the bottom of your page.

[image: Kittens photo from pexel]
(photo from pexels.com)

```html
<<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Gray then color</title>
    <style>
      div {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
      }
      .graythencolor {
        background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQeNg.jpg"), linear-gradient(0deg, white 10%, black 20%, black 100%), url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQeNg.jpg");
        background-position: 0px 0px, 0px 0px, 0px 0px;
        background-size: cover, 100% 80%, cover;
        background-repeat:no-repeat no-repeat, no-repeat no-repeat, no-repeat no-repeat;
        background-blend-mode: luminosity, multiply;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="graythencolor"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```